# Convert "Fri 12/25/20" to date 2020-12-25 in bigquery

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I uploaded a google sheet into BQ and the date format is "DOW mm/dd/yyyy" and of course BQ recognizes it as a string.  I want to convert it to date without the DOW. How can I do this without changing the date format in google sheets (which is not an option)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below

```
select parse_date('%a %m/%d/%y', 'Fri 12/25/20')
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the CAST as DATE function with the appropriate format string

Comment: shouldn't you add that forma string?

Comment: Assuming that comment was addressed to me, then my personal preference is not to just give people the answer but to give them the tools so they can solve the issue for themselves (or come back with a specific question) - that way there is a much better chance of the questioner understanding the solution and being able to solve similar issues for themselves in the future. However, that’s just me, if someone else wants to provide the full solution then that’s fine